# Textarea and StringLength validator on server side count 'enter' as two characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a `StringLength` validator on textarea

```
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be {1} characters or less")]
```

So when I press `enter` and then type 9 characters, the client validation does not display any errors; but if I submit the form, server validation says that there is more than 10 characters.

So on client side `enter` means one character and on server, two. It is not the same behavior.

Probably I would need to implement my own validator which would do it, right?

Or is there any validators I may use instead of `StringLength`, to validate `textarea` content length correctly?

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here: [New line characters in text area increases text length in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241076/new-line-characters-in-text-area-increases-text-length-in-c-sharp/11365490#11365490)

You can change the default behavior for getLength to double count newlines by adding the following to your JS somewhere.

```
$.validator.prototype._getLength = $.validator.prototype.getLength;
$.validator.prototype.getLength = function (value, element) {
// Double count newlines in a textarea because they'll be turned into \r\n by the server. 
    if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'textarea')
        return value.length + value.split('\n').length - 1;
    return this._getLength(value, element);
};
```

Comment: Fixed: return value.length + value.match(/\n/g).length;

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute to your property

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\s\S]{0,10}$",ErrorMessage="maximun length must be 10")]
```

then in your view

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyText) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently, but since both the .Net code and Sql Server were considering one line break as two chars, I ended up changing the client side logic to also consider line breaks as two chars:

```
$('textarea[maxlength]').keyup(function () {
    var lineBreaks = $(this).val().split('\n').length - 1;
    var charsUsed = $(this).val().length + lineBreaks;
    if (charsUsed >= maxlength) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, maxlength - lineBreaks));
        charsUsed = maxlength;
    }            
    var remaining = maxlength - charsUsed;
    $('#MyCounter').html("<strong>" + remaining + "</strong> characters remaining");
});
```