# Value to large for column via nhibernate but ok in toad for oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, nhibernate, toad

Given this field in an Oracle table:

```
ColumnName varchar(255 byte)
```

Given this string:

```
-- abcd abcdefghijkl mnokpqrstuvwxy abcd ab abcdefgh abc def abc
abcdef ab.* abcd
abcdefgh ij
abcd abcdefghijkl mn ab ab.cd = ef.abcdefghijk ab ab.cd = ab.cdabe
abcd abcdefghi.jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc de ef ea.fd = ef.aezerfds
azere
fr.qsdfrtd = 1
fds ad.dfdsq
```

We insert this text into the specified column with a simple insert statement with the help of toad for oracle: that works fine.

However: if we insert this text with the help of nhibernate we will get an oracle error:

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column [**SNIP**] (actual: 262, maximum: 255)
```

This error is actually correct if you do a byte count of the given string, we will get a count of 262.

Why does nhibernate fail and why does toad for oracle succeed for the same action?

Has anyone any experience with this problem or something related to it?

**Edit**

Worth to mention here is that the string has been submitted in a html textarea. Possible problem here is that a return is counted as 1 character in the browser but it should be counted as more then 1 character since in .net it is represented by \r\n.

All this in a asp.net mvc scenario.

Comment: Partially similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241076/new-line-characters-in-text-area-increases-text-length-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://ashleyglee.com/maxlength-on-html-textarea-form-element/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/chrome-counts-characters-wrong-in-textarea-with-maxlength-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The actual problem:**

It has nothing to do with nhibernate or oracle.
When a textarea with newlines is posted to the "backend" of asp.net mvc we recieve those newlines as **\r\n**. It counts as 2 characters, which results in **2 bytes** for the database save.

However in our situation we have a maxlength=255 html attribute. The browser counts a newline as **1 character**. See the difference?

**The solution**

We solved it by replacing \r\n with \n.

```
public class NewLineModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.AttemptedValue) &&
                bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string))
            {
                var value = result.AttemptedValue;
                var replacedValue = value.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

                return replacedValue;
            }
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
```